# Is it possible to change the ComboBox popup position based on available space in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I've got a problem with the Combobox popup position. In my project, I expected the Combobox popup to be on either the right or left side, so I decided to change the horizontal offset of the popup. The popup will offset as I expected, but the issue is when I specify the value for horizontal offset. The popup couldn't adjust the position based on the available space.

Here I attached the code in which I specified the value for offset,

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
        <VisualState.Setters>                                                
            <Setter Target="Popup.HorizontalOffset"
                    Value="50" />
         </VisualState.Setters>
    <Storyboard>                                                
    <SplitOpenThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
                             ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
                             OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
    <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
    <Storyboard>                                                
    <SplitCloseThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
                                ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}" />
    </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Is there any suggestion to overcome this issue? Either in XAML or C#.

Answer (score 0):

It'd better if we can do this by overriding the `ControlTemplate` but I couldn't find a way. So, let me suggest you an alternative by creating a control derived from `ComboBox`.

**CustomComboBox.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ComboBoxTest;

public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public CustomComboBox() : base()
    {
        this.Loaded += CustomComboBox_Loaded;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildrenOfType<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            if (child is T hit)
            {
                yield return hit;
            }

            foreach (T? grandChild in FindChildrenOfType<T>(child))
            {
                yield return grandChild;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CustomComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FindChildrenOfType<Popup>(this).FirstOrDefault() is Popup popup)
        {
            popup.PlacementTarget = this;
            popup.DesiredPlacement = PopupPlacementMode.RightEdgeAlignedBottom;
        }
    }
}
```

And just use it like a usual `ComboBox`.

**.xaml**

```xml
<local:CustomComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Text1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Text2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Text3" />
</local:CustomComboBox>
```

Comment: I'm explaining a bit more in this [video](https://youtu.be/ai-koyvgbWY).